# how to setup a custom preloader between html pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

I made a custom preloader for my website, now I want to use this preloader when you navigate to the website and when you switch between the html pages on the site.

I did some research around but didn't clarify how you would set this preloader up in code. I hope someone can help me :P I am new in the developing scene so yeah.

```css
#camera-body,
#reel-1,
#reel-2 {
 fill: #fff;
 fill-opacity: 0.95;
 stroke: none;
}

body {
 height: 100vh;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
 display: flexbox;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
  background-image: url( https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/200000/velka/plain-red-background.jpg); 
}

span {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>preloader</title>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon/popcorn-32.png">
</head>

<body>
<svg
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org"
 id="camera-loader"
   width="85.708488"
   height="100">
  <defs
     id="defs12" />
  <path
  id="camera-body"
     d="M 51.5625 0 C 50.667739 -0.00962983 49.756943 0.05800477 48.84375 0.1875 C 41.018415 1.2971691 35.117198 7.3376842 33.8125 14.71875 C 30.504071 7.9918491 23.138091 3.8277945 15.3125 4.9375 C 5.573576 6.3185261 -1.1937811 15.321773 0.1875 25.0625 C 1.030765 31.00916 4.7245026 35.850708 9.6875 38.40625 L 10.59375 44.84375 L 41.21875 40.5 C 42.618434 40.301472 43.966737 41.101389 44.15625 42.4375 C 44.34576 43.773612 43.274684 44.957723 41.875 45.15625 L 11.25 49.5 L 12.40625 57.6875 C 12.593105 59.005185 13.837018 59.937079 15.15625 59.75 L 64.25 52.78125 C 65.567815 52.594377 66.499355 51.348937 66.3125 50.03125 L 63.5625 30.78125 C 67.618077 26.946961 69.843395 21.259142 69 15.3125 C 67.748216 6.4849658 60.211858 0.09304631 51.5625 0 z M 51.28125 3.75 C 58.168631 3.6506107 64.22589 8.6859174 65.21875 15.6875 C 66.295328 23.279482 61.029156 30.329715 53.4375 31.40625 C 45.84552 32.482829 38.795329 27.18573 37.71875 19.59375 C 36.641441 11.998855 41.938942 4.9828747 49.53125 3.90625 C 50.124347 3.8221462 50.697574 3.7584222 51.28125 3.75 z M 17.5625 8.53125 C 24.449868 8.4318561 30.507144 13.46718 31.5 20.46875 C 32.576577 28.060719 27.310389 35.110969 19.71875 36.1875 C 12.126783 37.264077 5.0765804 31.966969 4 24.375 C 2.9226914 16.780121 8.2202041 9.7641225 15.8125 8.6875 C 16.405598 8.603395 16.978824 8.5396714 17.5625 8.53125 z M 79.71875 27.46875 L 66.9375 33.65625 L 68.53125 44.8125 L 82.53125 47.21875 L 79.71875 27.46875 z M 41.71875 41.0625 C 41.582761 41.058251 41.422178 41.073761 41.28125 41.09375 L 8.15625 45.78125 L 7.90625 44.09375 L 2.78125 43.9375 L 4 52.53125 L 8.875 50.9375 L 8.625 49.25 L 41.78125 44.5625 C 42.908673 44.40259 43.699053 43.493996 43.5625 42.53125 C 43.443014 41.688847 42.670671 41.092246 41.71875 41.0625 z M 51.53125 57.21875 L 28.625 60.4375 C 28.625117 63.279515 28.625057 61.501735 28.625 64.34375 L 30.90625 64.34375 L 32.40625 64.34375 L 17.21875 97.46875 C 16.804629 98.371268 17.19123 99.429629 18.09375 99.84375 C 18.996268 100.25787 20.054629 99.87127 20.46875 98.96875 L 36.34375 64.34375 L 38.28125 64.34375 L 38.28125 98.21875 C 38.28125 99.211743 39.069507 100 40.0625 100 C 41.055493 100 41.875 99.211743 41.875 98.21875 L 41.875 64.34375 L 43.6875 64.34375 L 59.71875 98.96875 C 60.136118 99.869771 61.192729 100.26112 62.09375 99.84375 C 62.994771 99.426382 63.386118 98.338521 62.96875 97.4375 L 47.65625 64.34375 L 49.09375 64.34375 L 51.53125 64.34375 L 51.53125 57.21875 z " />
  <path
     id="reel-1"
     d="m 17.763265,10.60917 c -1.849868,0 -3.349902,1.500036 -3.349902,3.349902 0,1.849868 1.500034,3.34863 3.349902,3.34863 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.498762 3.348629,-3.34863 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349902 -3.348629,-3.349902 z m -8.0539896,5.851215 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499023,1.500032 -3.3499023,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.5000343,3.349897 3.3499023,3.349897 1.8498656,0 3.3498996,-1.500031 3.3498996,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.500034,-3.349898 -3.3498996,-3.349898 z m 16.1016246,0 c -1.849868,0 -3.3499,1.500032 -3.3499,3.349898 0,1.849866 1.500032,3.349897 3.3499,3.349897 1.849865,0 3.348629,-1.500031 3.348629,-3.349897 0,-1.849866 -1.498764,-3.349898 -3.348629,-3.349898 z m -13.023579,9.460259 c -1.849867,0 -3.3498994,1.500032 -3.3498994,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.5000324,3.348629 3.3498994,3.348629 1.849867,0 3.3499,-1.498764 3.3499,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500033,-3.349902 -3.3499,-3.349902 z m 9.950613,0 c -1.849866,0 -3.348629,1.500032 -3.348629,3.349902 0,1.849865 1.498763,3.348629 3.348629,3.348629 1.849865,0 3.349901,-1.498764 3.349901,-3.348629 0,-1.84987 -1.500036,-3.349902 -3.349901,-3.349902 z">
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       attributeType="XML"
       type="rotate"
       dur="2s"
       begin="0"
       from="0 17.66 22.74"
       to="360 17.66 22.74"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
  <path
     id="reel-2"
     d="m 51.483904,5.8171007 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.5000388 -3.349908,3.3499074 0,1.8498709 1.500036,3.3486359 3.349908,3.3486359 1.849868,0 3.348635,-1.498765 3.348635,-3.3486359 0,-1.8498686 -1.498767,-3.3499074 -3.348635,-3.3499074 z M 43.4299,11.668326 c -1.849872,0 -3.349908,1.500034 -3.349908,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349908,3.349903 1.849869,0 3.349906,-1.500034 3.349906,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.500037,-3.349904 -3.349906,-3.349904 z m 16.101654,0 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349904 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.349903 3.349907,3.349903 1.849867,0 3.348635,-1.500034 3.348635,-3.349903 0,-1.84987 -1.498768,-3.349904 -3.348635,-3.349904 z m -13.023602,9.460276 c -1.849871,0 -3.349907,1.500034 -3.349907,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.500036,3.348635 3.349907,3.348635 1.849869,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500036,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z m 9.950632,0 c -1.849872,0 -3.348637,1.500034 -3.348637,3.349908 0,1.849869 1.498765,3.348635 3.348637,3.348635 1.849867,0 3.349905,-1.498766 3.349905,-3.348635 0,-1.849874 -1.500038,-3.349908 -3.349905,-3.349908 z">
    <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       attributeType="XML"
       type="rotate"
       dur="3.6s"
       begin="0"
       from="0 51.4 17.7"
       to="360 51.4 17.7"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </path>
</svg>

<span>Website loading&hellip;</span>
```

Comment: What is expected behavior?  Each page load creates new window instance and there is no state stored from prior page

Comment: @charlietfl
 so you tell me now that it is not possible ??

Comment: Depends on what your expectations are. There is no way to maintain part of a page until next page has fully loaded. Suggest you read up on how browser page loading works and page lifecycle

Comment: Do you have maybe a javascript solution how you can display it when you navigate to a other page? @charlietfl

Comment: You can use unload event to show in current page but I really think you need a better understanding how page lifecycle works because that won't prevent flash as current page gets wiped out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not easy to do, but if you want this kind of transition, check barba.js http://barbajs.org

Comment: I already fixed it :P but thanks for your website, gonna save it in my browser for the future :)

Answer (score 1):

**Do this:**

1- Save the preloader as a svg file.

2- Place the following code on each of the website pages:

```
<div id="preloader">
  <div id="camera"></div>
</div>
```

3- Add a link to CSS and JS files on each of the website pages.

**Example:**

```js
$(window).on( 'load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
  $( '#camera' ).fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
  $( '#preloader' ).delay( 350 ).fadeOut( 'slow' ); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
  $( 'body' ).delay( 350 ).css( { 'overflow': 'visible' } );
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden
}
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: url( https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/200000/velka/plain-red-background.jpg);
  z-index: 99; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
#camera {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
  top: 50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/6js.svg); /* path to your loading animation */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin: -150px 0 0 -150px /* is width and height divided by two */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="preloader">
  <div id="camera"></div>
</div>

<!-- page contents here -->
<img width="100%" src='https://unsplash.it/3000/3000/?random' />
```

**Each time you run the above code snippet, First, the preloader is displayed and then the contents of the page.**